# alternative way to construct pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3], 
           'b': [0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0,0,1,1,], 
                   'c': [5,5,5,8,9,9,6,6,7,8,9,9]})

>>> df
    a  b  c
0   1  0  5
1   1  0  5
2   1  1  5
3   1  1  8
4   2  0  9
5   2  0  9
6   2  1  6
7   2  1  6
8   3  0  7
9   3  0  8
10  3  1  9
11  3  1  9
```

Is there an alternative way to get this output?

```
>>> pd.pivot_table(df, index=['a','b'], columns='c', aggfunc=len, fill_value=0).reset_index()
c  a  b  5  6  7  8  9
0  1  0  2  0  0  0  0
1  1  1  1  0  0  1  0
2  2  0  0  0  0  0  2
3  2  1  0  2  0  0  0
4  3  0  0  0  1  1  0
5  3  1  0  0  0  0  2
```

I have a large `df` (>~1m lines) with `len(df.c.unique())` being 134 so `pivot` is taking forever.

I was thinking that, given that this result is returned within a second in my actual `df`:

```
>>> df.groupby(by = ['a', 'b', 'c']).size().reset_index()
   a  b  c  0
0  1  0  5  2
1  1  1  5  1
2  1  1  8  1
3  2  0  9  2
4  2  1  6  2
5  3  0  7  1
6  3  0  8  1
7  3  1  9  2
```

whether I could manually construct the desired outcome from this output above

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### 1. Here's one:

```
df.groupby(by = ['a', 'b', 'c']).size().unstack(fill_value=0).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
c  a  b  5  6  7  8  9
0  1  0  2  0  0  0  0
1  1  1  1  0  0  1  0
2  2  0  0  0  0  0  2
3  2  1  0  2  0  0  0
4  3  0  0  0  1  1  0
5  3  1  0  0  0  0  2
```

#### 2. Here's another way:

```
pd.crosstab([df.a,df.b], df.c).reset_index()
```

Output:

```
c  a  b  5  6  7  8  9
0  1  0  2  0  0  0  0
1  1  1  1  0  0  1  0
2  2  0  0  0  0  0  2
3  2  1  0  2  0  0  0
4  3  0  0  0  1  1  0
5  3  1  0  0  0  0  2
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Just for the sake of future readers, with my `df`, as described in OQ, approach 1 is ~ 20x faster than approach 2.